# Update objects in list from objects in another list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a better way to write the below:

```
private fun updateImportantProperty(
    firstList: List<MyObjectX>?,
    secondList: List<MyObjectX>?
) {
    firstList?.forEach { item1 ->
        secondList?.forEach { item2 ->
            if (relatesInSomeWayToEachOther(item1, item2)) {
                item1.importantProperty = item2.importantProperty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of the above code could be that 1 object of firstList was updated or that 7 objects were (if the lists had 7 objects in common).

I just want to update that one important property of the objects in firstList. Assume nothing of the list such as sortedness or size, or if all objects are in both lists. Readability is what I'm after.

Comment: One for loop, ask if First list contains the other and than update it according to the position

Comment: Probably mine is a silly question, but is `importantProperty` part of the `equals()` method? If so, maybe you want to reverse the `if` condition, otherwise that code is useless

Comment: If `if (item1 == item2)` then `item1.importantProperty == item2.importantProperty` right? So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Adam but then the code makes even less sense... if `item1` and `item2` are the same object, how could they have different values for `importantProperty`?

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, tripped myself up, they are not the same object and importantProperty is not part of equals!

Comment: so: if the second list contains 3 matching objects then the same item on the first list needs to be updated 3 times too? the same also vice-versa... if you have 3 equal objects in list1 you need to update all 3 of them?

Comment: how is the equality evaluated? may it make sense to have a `Map` in place?

Comment: @Roland if there is an answer which depends on that objects from `firstList` are only updated at most once I would be interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to map first list by replacing certain property value with last matching property from the second list. It would certainly be easier if you would give a little more context, but I will try to simplify your syntax:

```
firstList?.map { 
  firstListElement -> secondList
    ?.filter { it.relatesInSomeWayTo(firstListElement) }
    ?.lastOrNull()
    ?.let { firstListElement.copy(property = it.property) }
      ?: firstListElement 
}
```

I believe that it would be more Kotlin way.

Please notice also two optional tweaks - first, your “relatesTo” function should be extension function on MyObjectX. Second, it should be immutable and therefore, use copy instead of assigning property.

EDIT:
sorry, that wouldn't compile. `filter` function returns list, not object, so you need to add `lastOrNull()` call. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the lists get big, iterating over the whole second list for each of the items of the first list becomes slow, as it takes `O(n^2)` time.

If matching items are rare (i.e. there won't be a lot of matches for each of the first list's items, just a few of them), you might want to build an index of some sort by extracting what is really meaningful for `relatesInSomeWayToEachOther` from all items of the second the lists and then doing a quick lookup for each item of the first list.

For example:

```
val secondListIndex = secondList.groupBy { getIndexKey(it) }

firstList.forEach { item1 ->
    val matchingSecondListItems = secondListLookup[getLookupKey(item1)].orEmpty()
    matchingSecondListItems.forEach { item2 ->
        item1.importantProperty = item2.importantProperty
    }
}
```

I used two functions here, `getIndexKey` and `getLookupKey`, but this may be the same function if the matching criteria are simple.

Comment: not looking for running-time optimisations. Readability is king, was looking for some neat kotlin-collection function or two which maybe could be made to do this without two `forEach`es and an `if`. I guess it's kinda clear with the forEaches

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `Map` doesn't make sense and as you mentioned that time complexity is not an issue, I will only concentrate on how that code could be improved in regards to readability.

A little improvement regarding performance I would introduce nonetheless, i.e. you do not have to call the `firstList.forEach` if the second list is empty/`null`. Additionally, as this seems a rather special use case I would rather add an extension function for it, so that it is even more clear, which list is updated by what, e.g.:

```
fun List<MyObjectX>.updateBy(other: List<MyObjectX>?) {
  if (other != null && other.isNotEmpty())
    forEach { thisItem ->
      other.filter { relatesInSomeWayToEachOther(thisItem, it) }
           .forEach { thisItem.importantProperty = it.importantProperty }
    }
}
```

so using it is more readable I think, e.g.:

```
val oneNullable : List<MyObjectX>? = ...
val twoNotNull : List<MyObjectX>? = ...

oneNullable?.updateBy(twoNotNull)
// or vice-versa
twoNotNull.updateBy(oneNullable)
```

Regarding, objects that should be updated at most once the inner loop slightly changes:

```
fun List<MyObjectX>.updateOnceBy(other: List<MyObjectX>?) {
  if (other != null && other.isNotEmpty()))
    forEach { thisItem ->
      other.firstOrNull { 
        relatesInSomeWayToEachOther(thisItem, it)
      }?.also {
        thisItem.importantProperty = it.importantProperty
      }
    }
}
```

Well... I see... I value the readability on the caller side higher then the one of the implementing side ;-)

Maybe splitting it up helps regarding readibility:

```
fun MyObjectX.updateBy(other: List<MyObjectX>) {
  other.filter { this == it } // or if only first applies, firstOrNull again
       .forEach { importantProperty = it.importantProperty }
}

fun List<MyObjectX>.updateBy(other: List<MyObjectX>?) {
  if (other != null && other.isNotEmpty())
    forEach {
      it.updateBy(other)
    }
}
```

But I think that something like a `Map` will not only improve time complexity, but also readability...